# How do I change the colours of the Switch component?

Tags: codenameone

I want to change the colour of the thumb of the Switch component to green instead of the standard black.

According to the documentation "You can customize the look and feel of a switch using styles, either directly in the theme.res file or in CSS." and "The thumb will be rendered using Switch's Style.getFgColor(). It will use the selected style, when in the "on" position, the unselected style when in the "off" position,"
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/Switch.html

I have tried adding a "Switch" style to the theme.res file.  In the theme preview I see my changes.  When I run the app in the simulator, there is no change.
I also tried changing the style in code:

```
 swPrdp.setUIID("Switch");
```

I still get the standard black thumb.
I also tried:

```
    swPrdp.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xcccccc, true);
    swPrdp.getSelectedStyle().setFgColor( 0x59925A, true);
```

with and without the second argument (true).  Still no change.

I am trying to keep the app size to a minimum, so I don't want to go the route of specifying images.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in the theme too and works for me in the style object (which is easier to write here:

```
Form hi = new Form("Switch", BoxLayout.y());
Switch s = new Switch();
s.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xff0000);
s.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff);
hi.add(s);

hi.show();
```

[image]